# Split file content into groups by header

Tags: regex, split, powershell-2.0

I have a file with content that looks like this:

```
[Something1Something2]
 - Interesting data 1
 - Interesting data 2

[Something3]
 - Interesting data 1
 - Interesting data 2

[Something4]
 - Interesting data 1
 - Interesting data 2
```

I would like to use spilt or some other to me unknown command to get the sections returned which i then can index like so:

```
$myStringArray[0]

prints:

 - Interesting data 1
 - Interesting data 2
```

I have tried to achieve this by using regex but with no luck:

```
"[Somthing1] somedata1 [Something2] somedate2" -split "\[(.*)\]"
```

I realize that this is not multiline as the above but principle is the same and only for testing.

If I do this with the above file to try it out with multilines:

```
$myfile = Get-Content .\test.txt
($myfile -split "\[.*\]")
```

I get an array of 14 and not 3 entries.

Comment: There is a difference in Regex between multiline and single line matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, however not a pretty one:

```
Function GetEntriesMatching($filename, $tagMatch)
{
    Write-Host "Filename: $filename"
    Write-Host "Tag: $tagMatch"

    $regex = "\[.*($tagMatch).*\]"
    Write-Host "Regex: $regex"

    $Lines = Get-Content $filename
    $Out = $False
    $returnValue = @()

    ForEach ($Line In $Lines)
    {
        If ($Line -match '\[.*\]') {$Out = $False}
        If ($Out -eq $True) {$returnValue += "<br> $Line </br>"}
        If ($Line -match $regex) {$Out = $True}
    }

    if($returnValue.Count -eq 0)
    {
        $returnValue += "<b>NO ENTRIES FOUND FOR $tagMatch</b>"
    }

    return $returnValue
}
```

If anyone has a slicker way of doing this i would really like to see it :).

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the regex:

```
(?mi)^\[.*\]{1}\s
```

To import the file, try this:

```
$myfile = [io.file]::ReadAllText(".\test.txt")
```

This will import the file as a single value, not an array that the get-content returns.

From there you should be able to do this:

```
[regex]::Split($myfile,"(?mi)^\[.*\]{1}\s")
```

This will not include the search string in the split.

If you want to include the search string, you need to us a lookahead, like this:

```
[regex]::Split($myfile,"(?=(?mi)^\[.*\]{1}\s)")
```